# Searching JSON keys by keywords

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a JSON list like this:

```
{
    "StatTrak™ AK-47 | Fire Serpent (Field-Tested)": 701,
    "StatTrak™ AK-47 | Fire Serpent (Minimal Wear)": 1050,
    "StatTrak™ AK-47 | Fire Serpent (Well-Worn)": 450.15,
    "StatTrak™ AK-47 | Fire Serpent (Factory New)": 3300,
    "AK-47 | Fire Serpent (Field-Tested)": 195.8,
    "StatTrak™ AK-47 | Fire Serpent (Battle-Scarred)": 369.58,
    "AK-47 | Fire Serpent (Factory New)": 750,
}
```

If user types in the box example: `ak fire serpent` then it would only return all the `ak fire serpents`

Here is my code what I have tried to use:

```
var itemWanted = 'ak fire serpent';
    var message = itemWanted.split(" ");
    for(var price in prices){
        var splitfast = price.split(" ");
        if(price.toLowerCase().includes(message[1].toLowerCase())){
            if(splitfast[1].toLowerCase().includes(message[0].toLowerCase())){
                console.log(price + ' - ' + prices[price]);
            }
        }
    }
```

It splits the user message and tries to find it, but it will try to search by name `fire` right now as an example, but there are like ~30 items with name `fire` in it, so I added 2nd part of code which checks the weapon type, but then it only returns me `StatTrak` ones because it checks `1` so what is the best way of doing it because splitting doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, I do not know where you get the JSON File from, but if you have the chance to change the JSON format a bit without putting a lot of effort in it, I would try to built the JSON structure a bit "smarter".

For example:

```
{
    "Weapon Type": {
       "StatTrak™ AK-47" : {
             "Fire Serpent": {
                 "(Field-Tested)": 1050,
                 "(Factory New)" : 50
             }
       }
       "AK-47" : 
             "Fire Serpent": {
                 "(Field-Tested)": 1050,
                 "(Factory New)" : 50
             }
        }
}
```

It might just help you to run through the JSON File a lot smoother and in an intuitive way.

Answer (score 0):

You can run through the keys of an object, like the example below, rather easily and see if any matches are found:

```js
var json = {
  'apple pear banana': 1,
  'apple peach banana': 2,
  'apple grape banana': 3,
  'apple pear peach': 4,
  'apple grape peach': 5,
}
var matches = 'peach grape'.split(' ');
var result = Object.keys( json ).filter(function( key ){
  return !!(matches.find(function( match ){
    return key.indexOf( match ) >= 0
  }));
});

console.log( result, result.map(key => json[key]) );
```